# SVG Shape Lighting

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vector-graphics, svg-filters

**Summary:** I'm trying to create a canvas of randomized rock climbing holds using vector graphics generated with properties such as color, rotation, size and path values.
To add depth to these I'm trying to add a sort of randomized shadow to them to show that one or more sides of the shape are raised from the background.

**Question:**
I've been able to apply this filter onto the svg however as you can see on the below image ***"Light Filter"*** I get this white effect bleeding out to the edge of the svg element.
I'd like to find a way to keep that raised effect and have the color show or find a new way to show shadow randomized to each edge of the svg path?

You can find the filter code in the function: **addFilter**

You can disable the filter effect by commenting out the function **addFilter();** and **applyFilter();**

**No Filter:**

[image]

**Light Filter:**

[image]

```js
      //create a filter for the svg copying the rough paper filter and apply it to the svg
      var filter = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "filter");
      filter.setAttribute("id", "roughpaper");
      filter.setAttribute("x", "0%");
      filter.setAttribute("y", "0%");
      filter.setAttribute("width", "100%");
      filter.setAttribute("height", "100%");
      var feDiffuseLighting = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feDiffuseLighting");
      feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("in", "noise");
      feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("lighting-color", "#ffffff");
      feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("surfaceScale", "2");
      var feDistantLight = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feDistantLight");
      feDistantLight.setAttribute("azimuth", "45");
      feDistantLight.setAttribute("elevation", "60");
      feDiffuseLighting.appendChild(feDistantLight);
      filter.appendChild(feDiffuseLighting);
      document.getElementById("svg-0").appendChild(filter);
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #333;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #svg-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .svg-element {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
      <svg
        viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        preserveAspectRatio="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        version="1.1"
        class="svg-element"
        id="svg-0"
        filter="url(#roughpaper)"
      >
        <path
          d="M27.8,-30.1C31.8,-29.8,27.8,-17,30.3,-5C32.9,7,42,18.2,38.3,19.7C34.5,21.1,18,12.7,4.6,21.4C-8.9,30.1,-19.3,55.9,-25.4,58.5C-31.5,61.2,-33.3,40.7,-44.1,24.4C-54.8,8,-74.4,-4.3,-75.5,-15.9C-76.6,-27.6,-59.1,-38.6,-43.4,-36.8C-27.7,-34.9,-13.9,-20.3,-1,-19.1C11.9,-17.9,23.9,-30.3,27.8,-30.1Z"
          transform="translate(100, 100)"
          class="path"
          id="path-0"
          style="fill: rgb(106, 76, 147)"
        ></path>
        
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has runnable "stack snippets" so if your problem is with a pure html/css/js bit of code, [please use those](/help/how-to-ask) rather than linking out to codepen or the like. (And then of course post it as [mcve] rather than as full codebase. Almost nothing in your fairly huge codepen is relevant to the problem, so you can leave a _lot_ out)

Comment: Please remember not to just paste in your code from codepen: really do turn it into an [mcve]. There's way more code in your snippet right now than there needs to be: you just need a single SVG to show the problem, almost none of the CSS contributes to the problem, none of the scripts you're loading are actually necessary, and almost none of the JS is relevant to reproduce the problem you're trying to solve. (you're basically trying to show as little code as possible, including hardcoding whatever can be, such as just putting the SVG itself directly into the runnable HTML)

Comment: Will do just reading into it.

Comment: Hi Mike, hopefully the changes I've made follow those guide lines?
Its as minimal as I can get it.

Comment: that's still a lot of code that just isn't required. Put the two SVGs in your html, _and the filter elements_. You're doing a ton in JS right now just to build DOM nodes: hardcode those as plain HTML. The problem is in using them, not in generating them, so focus on that.

Comment: Hi Mike I appreciate the advice, I've attempted to minimize this even more.
No longer generating or apply other properties just what the question entails.

Comment: Nice, that's a good MCVE. On a modern JS note though, try not to use `var`, because it doesn't scope the way every other programming language scopes vars. Instead, use the "modern" (6 years old by now =D) `let` for mutable variables (e.g. can be assigned a new value) and `const` for immutable variables.

Comment: Added an initial blur to give the light an alpha gradient to shine onto - forgot that. And made the light a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffuse light effects should be multiplied with the original, otherwise you'll see the the lighting color rather than the combination of original color + lighting. So just add a feBlend with a multiply - like so. Update: and then add a feComposite/in to "clip to self" - so you don't see the background lit with the light as well.

```js
//create an array with multiple svg paths
var svgPaths = [
  {
    path: "M27.8,-30.1C31.8,-29.8,27.8,-17,30.3,-5C32.9,7,42,18.2,38.3,19.7C34.5,21.1,18,12.7,4.6,21.4C-8.9,30.1,-19.3,55.9,-25.4,58.5C-31.5,61.2,-33.3,40.7,-44.1,24.4C-54.8,8,-74.4,-4.3,-75.5,-15.9C-76.6,-27.6,-59.1,-38.6,-43.4,-36.8C-27.7,-34.9,-13.9,-20.3,-1,-19.1C11.9,-17.9,23.9,-30.3,27.8,-30.1Z",
  },
  {
    path: "M36.5,-45.3C49.8,-32.4,64.8,-23.2,69,-10.5C73.3,2.2,66.7,18.5,58.3,34.1C49.8,49.8,39.4,64.8,23.8,74.4C8.1,84,-12.7,88.2,-22.9,77.9C-33,67.7,-32.3,43,-35.4,26.1C-38.5,9.1,-45.3,0,-46.2,-10.5C-47.2,-21,-42.3,-32.7,-33.6,-46.4C-24.9,-60.1,-12.5,-75.7,-0.4,-75.2C11.6,-74.7,23.2,-58.1,36.5,-45.3Z",
  }
];
var colors = ["#FF595E", "#FFCA3A", "#8AC926", "#1982C4", "#6A4C93"];





//create a function to apply properties to each svg element
function holdProps() {
  //based on the id of the svg element, re-position the svg element on the screen
  var svgElements = document.getElementsByClassName("svg-element");
  //set the position of the svg element to the top left
  for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
    svgElements[i].style.position = "absolute";
    svgElements[i].style.top = "0";
    svgElements[i].style.left = "0";
  }
  //console log the bounding box of each svg element
  for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
    var svg = svgElements[i];
    console.log(svg.getBoundingClientRect());
  }
}

//create a function to apply properties to each svg elements path value
function holdPaths() {
  //create a path and append it to each svg element
  $(".svg-element").each(function () {
    var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

    //set attributes to the above created path
    path.setAttribute(
      "d",
      svgPaths[Math.floor(Math.random() * svgPaths.length)].path
    );
    path.setAttribute("transform", "translate(100, 100)");
    path.setAttribute("class", "path");
    path.setAttribute("id", "path-" + $(this).attr("id").split("svg-")[1]);
    this.appendChild(path);
  });

  //If a path id is clicked change the path to a random path with a random color
  $(".svg-element").click(function () {
    var path = svgPaths[Math.floor(Math.random() * svgPaths.length)].path;
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $(this).find("path").attr("d", path);
    $(this).find("path").css("fill", color);
  });
}

//create a function to apply random colors to each svg element
function colorHold() {
  $(".svg-element path").each(function () {
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $(this).css("fill", color);
    //stroke white width 5 if the svg is hoverd over
    $(this).hover(function () {
      $(this).css("stroke", "white");
      $(this).css("stroke-width", "5");
    }
    //reset stroke to black and stroke width to 1 if the svg is not hovered over
    , function () {
      $(this).css("stroke", "black");
      $(this).css("stroke-width", "0");
    }
    );
  });
}

//create feDistantLight and a fePointLight to each svg element
function addFilter() {
  var filter = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "filter");
    filter.setAttribute("id", "roughpaper");
    filter.setAttribute("x", "0%");
    filter.setAttribute("y", "0%");
    filter.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    filter.setAttribute("height", "100%");


var feGauss= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feGaussianBlur");
    feGauss.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "4");
    feGauss.setAttribute("result", "blur");
    filter.appendChild(feGauss);

  var feDiffuseLighting = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feDiffuseLighting");
    feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("in", "blur");
    feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("lighting-color", "#ffffff");
    feDiffuseLighting.setAttribute("surfaceScale", "6");

  var feDistantLight = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feDistantLight");
    feDistantLight.setAttribute("azimuth", "235");
    feDistantLight.setAttribute("elevation", "50");
  feDiffuseLighting.appendChild(feDistantLight);
  filter.appendChild(feDiffuseLighting);


var feBlend= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feBlend");
    feBlend.setAttribute("mode", "multiply");
    feBlend.setAttribute("in2", "SourceGraphic");
    filter.appendChild(feBlend);

var feComp= document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feComposite");
    feComp.setAttribute("operator", "in");
    feComp.setAttribute("in2", "SourceGraphic");
    filter.appendChild(feComp);

  document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(filter);
} 
//apply the filter to each svg element
function applyFilter() {
  var svgElements = document.getElementsByClassName("svg-element");
  for (var i = 0; i < svgElements.length; i++) {
    svgElements[i].setAttribute("filter", "url(#roughpaper)");
  }
}

//on load run the functions
$(document).ready(function () {
  //create a path for each svg element
  holdPaths();
  //apply properties to each svg element
  holdProps();
  //apply random colors to each svg element
  colorHold();

  //Disable these two to remove the filter
  //create a filter to each svg element
  addFilter();
  //apply the filter to each svg element
  applyFilter();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#svg-container {
  /* full size of page*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.svg-element {
  position: absolute;
  
}
svg path {
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="svg-container">
  <!-- Create SVG -->
  <svg id="svg-01" class="svg-element" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach it works quite well only issue left is the white effect filling the svg element itself?
I've got to read more into this feBlend as I'm very new to this.

Comment: Ah. You need to add a feComposite/in to "clip to self" - let me add that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response been crazy busy.
Yes this has worked and quite well, if you're interested here was the final result
https://codepen.io/timhow38/pen/rNdaeye